# Pass customized object to jQuery pop up in onclick event

Tags: jquery, playframework-2.0

I am using play framework 2.0. I have a list of items displayed in the scala template by iterating a list(List) of User object. Each user object is displayed in div's as,

```
<div class="columns"><code>
@for(list of Users) {
   <div class="column"> 
    <a class="popup-link" href="#drabbles-box">@user.TITLE</a></div>
 }
</div>
```

When that title is clicked a pop up opens as

```
<div class="popup-box-hover" style="display: none">
<div class="popup">
     @user.getImage() //HELP NEEDED HERE
</div>
```

The following is the jQuery code: 
   
`$(".popup-link").fancybox({
                zoomSpeedIn : 0,
                zoomSpeedOut : 0,
                frameWidth : 670,
                imageScale : false,
                hideOnContentClick : false,
                overlayOpacity : 0.6
            });`

```
        $(".popup-link").click(

                function() {

                    //alert(' ' + $("#currentDrabble").val())

                    if ($(this).parents().is('.box')) {
                        cur_title = $(this).parents('.box').find(
                                '.title-for-form').text();
                    }

                    return true;
                });

        $("#header .popup-link").click(function() {
            $('#chal').val($('#chal').attr('title'));
        })

        $(".part-chal").click(function() {
            $('#chal').val(cur_title);
            return true;
        });
```

I need to pass the user object to that jQuery pop up. I don't know how to pass the PARTICULAR object to show the image for that when the link is clicked. I dont know jQuery at All so I could not find where the pop up is called.

Please help.

Comment: `Pop-up window` or `modal` (or other `dialog box`) ? Show us the code opening it.

Comment: its jQuery pop up. added code in the description. The commented alert is working if uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you're on the JS side you won't have access to the User List...

So if you need the pop-up to contain various content related to the clicked item.
What you can do is (a quick and dirty way I'd say):
1/ for the item that are triggering the pop up (via click) you must add a specific attribute which holds the content to be displayed (I'm guessing the `@user.getImage` returns a url to the image) => look at the attribute `data-content` (we'll use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5))

```
<a class="popup-link" data-content="@user.getImage()" href="#drabbles-box">@user.TITLE</a></div>
```

2/ When triggering the pop up you can now change the content easily, like so

```
$(".popup-link").click(function() {
   if ($(this).parents().is('.box')) {
       cur_title = $(this).parents('.box').find('.title-for-form').text();
   }
   //create the img tag
   var image = $("<img></img>")
   //give it the url to the image for the current user
   image.attr("src", $(this).data("content")) //$(this) wraps the element being clicked
   //set the content of ".popup" to be this img tag
   $(".popup").html(image)
   return true;
});
```

I didn't tried it, so if there is any problems, comment and I'll continue helping by updating this answer with corrections.

HTH

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I have gone with the following code to call the server side with jQuery. $.getJSON("load-page?id="+id, function(data, status, xhr) { var myData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); } and then open the pop up with filled data. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem man. Just upvote it and approve it. So that others will find it as a solution directly.